Is there a way to yield from any of the generators
I have a function
async function* values(input) {
    ...
}

this will yield some values depending on the input.
Now I have a set of inputs, let's say [1,2,3,4,5], and I want to create another generator function that will use these inputs and call values for each of them.
I want to yield back from the wrapping generator function whenever any of the values call yields.
The function yields the generator sequentially:
function* generateValues() {
     const inputs = [1,2,3,4,5];

     const generators = inputs.map(input => values(input));

     for (const generator of generators) {
          yield await generator.next();
     }
}

but I want to yield as soon as any of the generators yields, and keep yielding till all generators are drained.
I would like to replace the for loop above, with something like:
for await (const value of Generator.any(generators)) {
    yield value;
}

i.e. I'm looking for something like Generator.any which would be similar to Promise.any but without throwing away the remaining generators.

The program given below maintains a sequence nexts of promises such that nexts[i] resolves to the value yielded by generators[i] and the index i. A loop uses Promise.any repeatedly to obtain the earliest such value (from any generator) and update nexts[i] with a promise for the next value from the same generator. But if the generator is done, the promise is effectively removed from nexts. The loop ends when all promises have been removed.
In this example, the values generator yields two values: the first comes the later the smaller its input is, the second comes the earlier the smaller its input is.


async function* values(input) {
  await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000 - input * 100);
  });
  yield input;
  await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, input * 200);
  });
  yield input + 10;
}

async function awaitNext(generator, index) {
  const next = await generator.next();
  return { index, next };
}

async function* Generator_any(generators) {
  let running = generators.length;
  const nexts = generators.map(awaitNext);
  while (true) {
    const { index, next } = await Promise.any(nexts);
    if (next.done) {
      // Remove this promise
      nexts[index] = new Promise(() => {});
      if (--running === 0) return; // All promises removed
    } else {
      nexts[index] = awaitNext(generators[index], index); // Update this promise for the next value
      yield next.value;
    }
  }
}

(async function () {
  const inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const generators = inputs.map((input) => values(input));
  for await (const i of Generator_any(generators)) console.log(i);
})();



